# Finding cause of SIGABRT EXC_CRASH in .NET MAUI app

Tags: ios, maui

I have a .NET MAUI app that is working fine on my iPhone but the AppStore has rejected it saying that it crashed when they tried to use it.

The following is from the crash report. I've done some research about this particular issue. One possibility is that a particular element in one of the pages is causing the crash.

Another possibility I've found is that it's the watchdog service is purposely crashing the app because it's taking too long for it to start up.

I'd appreciate others' input to help me find the actual cause of the crash. Here's part of the crash report that I think provides relevant data about the cause of the crash:

```
"exception" : {
   "codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000"
   "rawCodes":[0,0],
   "type":"EXC_CRASH",
   "signal":"SIGABRT"
},
"termination" : {
   "flags":0,
   "code":6,
   "namespace":"SIGNAL",
   "indicator":"Abort trap: 6",
   "byProc":"MyApp",
   "byPid":1620
},
"ktriageinfo" : "VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter\n",
"asi" : {
   "libsystem_c.dylib":[
      "abort() called"
   ]
},
"faultingThread" : 0
```

As I mentioned earlier, when I download the app from TestFlight and install it on my iPhone, it works perfectly fine.

The only thing I've noticed is that during debug in Visual Studio using HotReload, it stops the HotReload the first time I launch the app. If I start the debug session again, the second time, it launches and works fine. This makes me think it may actually be the watchdog crashing the app. Not sure what but something in my initialization process maybe tying up the system a little too long.

I'd appreciate any input/suggestions on this.

Here's a link to the full crash report file: [crash_report_data_20240201.txt](https://s3.amazonaws.com/iQuest/crash_report_data_20240201+.txt)